# How to play audio with MediaPlayer and use the MediaController

Tags: android, media-player, mediacontroller

I use below code to play audio:

```
    try {
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can show `MediaController` and to control `mMediaPlayer`?